# Adding a column through the terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do you add a column to a table using ActiveRecord through the terminal. I am trying to use add_column method but its not working. Any ideas please?

Comment: It's better to write a migration

Comment: Im using rail's default, which if I am not mistaken, is SQLite... However, its shouldn't matter as I am abstracting SQL code by using ActiveRecord. I generated an Account model and forgot to insert an email fieldname and wish to add it...

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW u write it using the add_column yes?

Comment: One thing to note: when running in a [sandboxed console](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-console), changes to the database schema are rolled back on exit. This is particularly interesting when writing one-way migrations. Starting a sandbox: `bin/rails console --sandbox`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is better to write a migration and a must if you are working with a team.  When you make db changes, then every developer's environment has to be updated also.  Otherwise, you will have some mad developers at you.

```
rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string
```

will generate

```
class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string
  end
end
```

Then you run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

**Edit:**

For a rails console command line check @tadman's answer or use what Bengala proposed like

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column :products, :part_number, :string
```

Comment: Thx for the help. With regards to the product model, I assume that you have to add the accessor to cater for the new column manually? Rails won't edit the model automatically?

Answer (score 27):

You can run migrations directly in rails console `rails c` with `ActiveRecord::Migration`

For your purpose the next command will do what you ask:

```
>   ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column :table_name, :field_name, :field_type
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Of course, it's better to write a migration almost all the time. But _sometimes_, you know exactly what you're doing and just want to run a change directly :)

Comment: Yes, but he didn't ask how to do a migration, he asked how to add a column through the terminal. And I think this is the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just hacking around, it's usually easier to manipulate the database using a SQLite client of some sorts than through the Rails DB layer.

If you're doing this for a project, create a proper migration file and run it.

If you're determined to do this, the `add_column` method is available through the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` driver object.